# How fussy are Laravel namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel-5

I seem to come across a couple of flavours of laravel namespace definitions (in the classes) and I'm wondering if some are better than others, or maybe even plain wrong.

1. `namespace mydomain\app\controllers`
2. `namespace dev.mydomain.com\app\controllers`
3. `namespace app\controllers`
4. `namespace \app\controllers`

A couple of questions:

- I know the initial `\` is optional, but what the mydomain prefix?  Is it required, or optional?
- does it make a difference to use `dev.mydomain.com` is or just `mydomain` ?
- Is it simply a matter of being the same as the folder names?

Comment: The initial slash refers to the [global namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php). Doesn't matter if you use `dev` or not before the namespace. It's just a namespace. Folder names are not related to the namespace per se, but some loaders do use the namespace as a mapping for folders. Have a look [here](https://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Is there a difference between `myproject\app\controllers` and `\app\controllers` and `app\controllers`?

Comment: Yes. There is. According to [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) loading standard, which laravel uses, the namespace must be `\<NamespaceName>(\<SubNamespaceNames>)*\<ClassName>` where `SubNamespaceNames` can be as many as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing better or worse in those namespaces you mention.

Namespaces were added to language to prevent name clashes in separate packages.

For example, you can have a class `User` in your own namespace `\MyApp\User`, and also use a third party package that has a class named `User`, but in its own namespace `\Package\User`.

That was the initial idea. Later, people decided that we can use this namespaces to auto-load some classes. A raw idea is that `\MyApp\User` should be found in `MyApp/User.php`. Pretty simple.

This has advanced of course, that you can read more about by searching "php autoloading" or better "composer autoloading".

And about that initial `\`, it does not matter in some places, but it matters somewhere else. When declaring a namespace it does not matter, e.g. `namespace \MyApp\User` is the same as `namespace MyApp\User`. Also the `use` statement behaves like this. But when you are going to use a class, i.e. `new \MyApp\User()` vs `new MyApp\User`, it does differ. You can find more information in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Ok, enough background. Your questions specifically.

> I know the initial \ is optional, but what the mydomain prefix? Is it required, or optional?

As for Laravel case, it is not optional. Look at `composer.json`, under `psr-4` you will find that the `app` folder has a defined prefix for namespace. That is what you should use for your classes (If they are in `app` folder). To read more, look for [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

> does it make a difference to use dev.mydomain.com is or just mydomain ?

I think I already mentioned the PSR-4, so use whatever is there.

> Is it simply a matter of being the same as the folder names?

That is also the PSR-4. Read more about it, and all your questions are answered.

But in short, we have two standards for autoloading classes based on namespaces in PHP: PSR-0 and PSR-4.

In PSR-0 (the old one), The directory structure had to match the namespace exactly, that is if your root folder were `src` and you class was named `\Package\User`, then you had `src/Package/User.php` in your file system.

In PSR-4, we can have namespace prefix for a directory. For example, you say that whatever is in folder `src`, it just starts with `\App\Package` namespace. The a class named `\App\Package\User` should reside in `src/User.php`, with correct namespace of course. That is what being used by Laravel, and most packages these days.